# How to find sum of arithmetic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Here's my question:

For the series shown, find n such that $S_{n} = -4290$:

42 + 34 + 26 + 18 + …

---

I don't want a direct answer to the question, just a way to determine $A_{n}$ so I can do the work on my own.

Edit: $n$ and $A_{n}$ are unknown at the moment.

Comment: Use the formula: $S_{n}=\frac{1}{2}n(a_{1}+a_{ n})$ where $S_{n}$ is the sum of the series, $a_{1}$ is the first element of the series, i.e. $42$, and $a_{n}$ is the $n$th element of the series, i.e. $42-(n-1)8$.

Comment: Well you do know that $n$ is such that $S_{n}=\frac{1}{2}n(50-8n)=-4290$.

Comment: @Amad Yes, but I can't figure out $A_{n}$ without knowing $n$.

Comment: It isn't hard to figure out that $A_{n}=42-8\cdot (n-1)$, then
$A_{1}=42$, $A_{2}=34$, $A_{3}=26$, $A_{4}=18$ and so on

Comment: @FlorisClaassens I cannot use that formula since $n$ is unknown. There are two unknown variables in this.

Comment: What is the other unknown variable besides $n$?

Comment: @FlorisClaassens Well, $n$ and $A_{n}$ are undefined, but $A_{n}$ can be determined after $n$ is found.

Comment: @SanguineL So you describe $a_{n}$ in terms of $n$ as I and Amad have done and use that to get the formula for $S_{n}$ I gave before.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

If you can find a formula $f(n)$ for the sum of the first $n$ terms, then you have only to solve $f(n)=-4290$ for $n$.

If the first term is $a$, and the difference between successive terms is $d$, then the terms are $a$, $a+d$, $a+2d$, $a+3d$, and so on.

The sum with one term is $a =\boxed{1a}$.

The sum with two terms is $a+ \underbrace{(a+d)}_{2\textrm{nd term}}=\boxed{2a+(1)d}$.

The sum with three terms is $\underbrace{2a+(1)d}_{\textrm{sum of }2\textrm{ terms}} + \underbrace{(a+2d)}_{3\textrm{rd term}}=\boxed{3a + (1+2)d}$.

The sum with four terms is $\underbrace{3a + (1+2)d}_{\textrm{sum of }3\textrm{ terms}} + \underbrace{(a+3d)}_{4\textrm{th term}}=\boxed{4a + (1+2+3)d}$.

The sum with five terms is $\underbrace{4a + (1+2+3)d}_{\textrm{sum of }4\textrm{ terms}} + \underbrace{(a+4d)}_{5\textrm{th term}}=\boxed{5a + (1+2+3+4)d}$.

So you need to ask yourself:

1. What are $a$ and $d$ for your sequence?
2. Do you know the formula for $1+2+3+\cdots+n$?
3. What would be the pattern above for the sum of $n$ terms?

Answer (score 0):

You have $a_n=42-8(n-1)$.  Now use the sum formula $$\begin  {align}-4290&=\frac 12n(a_1+a_n)\\&=\frac 12n(42+(42-8(n-1))\\
&=\frac 12n(84-8n+8)\\&=46n-4n^2\\
&4n^2-46n-4290=0\end {align}$$
and solve the quadratic for $n$

Answer (score 0):

$$u_p+u_{p+1}+...+u_n={\frac{u_p+u_n}{2}}(n-p+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

It isn't hard to figure out that $A_{n}=42-8\cdot (n-1)$, then
$$A_{1}=42$$
$$A_{2}=34$$ 
$$A_{3}=26$$ 
$$A_{4}=18$$ 
and so on...

$$S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(42-8\cdot (k-1))=\sum_{k=1}^{n}42-8\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)=42n-8(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}1)=42n-8(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k-n)$$
Since we know that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\text{ [sum of all natural numbers not greater than n] } = \frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}$, we can simplify:
$$S_{n}=42n-8\cdot \left(\frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}-n\right)=42n-4n\cdot(n+1)+8n=50n-4n\cdot(n+1)=50n-4n^{2}-4n=\color{red}{46n-4n^{2}}$$